# Expose only a part of my class

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Lets say i have a Class User with multiple properties. I'm building a REST based App so in my homepage  when I request for "user details" I need only a few properties from my User and rest from other classes. How do i write the class for the object which i would return for "user details" ?

My current design retrieves the needed properties from the class to build the JSON. I hope there is a better way to handle this.

I use Play Framework 2.0 with Java

Comment: Which programming language/framework do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to expose whole business class User, I'll build a second class, a DTO. This class provides only the desired data to be transfered by REST API.

```
User user = new User("admin");
// Set other properties
UserDetailsDTO userDetailsDTO = new UserDetails(user); //<- Transfer userDetailsDTO
```

Or if "user details" are important for your application, maybe you should consider to create a UserDetails class and use it inside your User class by composition.

```
public class User {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String address;
    UserDetails userDetails; // Composition <- Tranfer userDetails
}
```

Note: example where don in Java

Comment: note that the object i want to return may contain properties from other Classes too. eg. Mixture of properties from User and Courses classes

Comment: Then I'll use fisrt aproach, a specific class with needed data to be transfered by the API

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a Facade: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern.
It is a simple pattern that helps you expose methods/properties from a multiple classes. 
You can store references to objects in your Facade class and expose only those things you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of creating a View Model object, providing proper abstraction for the information required for that JSON.
More details about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

But this is typically used in the cases where view directly used in Views of the application. So careful analysis is required in use case mentioned above, since there is already JSON being created, creation of this View Model layer is really justified.